# Move axis title towards plot and keep combmatrix labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetr, upsetplot

I am trying to move the y axis title towards the ticks. However, I'm having trouble doing this without cutting off the combmatrix labels. I've tried both with `ggupset` and `ggplot` functions. See reprex below.

Thank you for your help!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggupset)
library(ggplot2)

tidy_pathway_member <- 
  gene_pathway_membership %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "Pathway") %>%
  tidyr::gather(Gene, Member, -Pathway) %>%
  filter(Member) %>%
  select(- Member)

g <-
  tidy_pathway_member %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarize(Pathways = list(Pathway)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pathways)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_upset()

g
```

[image]

```r
g +
  # Moves axis title towards ticks...but cuts off labels
  theme_combmatrix(combmatrix.label.make_space = FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
g +
  # Also, moves axis title towards ticks...but cuts off labels
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = -100)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Share a `dput()` with your data or a sample

Comment: `gene_pathway_membership` is a data frame from the `ggupset` package.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggupset)
library(ggplot2)

tidy_pathway_member <- 
  gene_pathway_membership %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "Pathway") %>%
  tidyr::gather(Gene, Member, -Pathway) %>%
  filter(Member) %>%
  select(- Member)

g <-
  tidy_pathway_member %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarize(Pathways = list(Pathway)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Pathways)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_upset() +
  # the exact vjust number needed may vary depending on the plotting area size
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=-30))

g
```

[image: vjust=-30]

BTW the same solution should work for ComplexUpset in principle.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a tricky way.

The solution is to hide the y axis title and add text with `annotate()` to the target position.

Since you did not provide your data, I will show it on an example.

Original plot:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut))
```

[image]

Version with `annotate` in place of the y-axis title:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = clarity)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = cut)) +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) + annotate(geom = "text", x = -0.2, y = 6500, label = "count", angle = 90, size=4) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 8), clip = "off")
```

[image]

You just need to set the appropriate `x` and `y` coordinates and `xlim` inside `coord_cartesian`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround suggestion. Would be great if there's a solution native to `ggupset`. The data comes with the package, so `ggupset:: gene_pathway_membership`

Comment: Unfortunately `annotate` isn't working with `ggupset`, I believe, due to the special x-axis. Any other suggestions? "Error in f(..., self = self) : Error in scale_upset for aesthetic 'x'. 'x' must be of type list. It currently is: character"